# mysql statement issue

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL statement that works fine in my query program (Navicat) however when I try and put this in a command in crystal it is throwing an error

The statement is

```
set @rownum=0
Select 
  @rownum := @rownum +1 as ranknum
  , cust_name
  ,  count(distinct callref) as rank 
from opencall 
where logdate like '%/08/2011%' 
  and companyname = "McDonald's Nederland" 
group by cust_name 
order by rank desc
```

The error is

> Failed to retrieve data from database. details 42000 [MYSQL] [ODBC 3.51 Driver] [mysqld-4.0.16] You have an error in your SQL syntax. Check the manual that corresponds with your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select @rownum :=@rownum +1 as ranknum,cust_name, count(dist [Database Vendor Code:1064 ]

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but please *never ever* say "it is throwing an error" without saying *which* error exactly. Always remember to quote the exact error message.

Comment: Have added messages apologies didn't realise my mistake would rile someone enough to downvote me

Comment: Downvoted, please explain what the expected result of the statement.

Comment: @Annette: It's not a question of "riling" people. It's common sense that if you want help you need to post the error message, otherwise how will people know what the problem is?

Comment: I am needing the ranknumber in a subreport in Crystal reports

Comment: well I sincerely apologise, it was a complete mistake I meant to add it and just missed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate statements using a `;`

```
set @rownum=0;
SELECT
  @rownum := @rownum +1 as ranknum
  , cust_name
  , COUNT(distinct callref) as rank 
FROM opencall 
WHERE logdate LIKE '%/08/2011%'    <<-- ?? dates are stored YYYY/MM/DD in a DB.
  AND companyname = "McDonald's Nederland" 
GROUP BY cust_name 
ORDER BY ranknum DESC   <<-- ranknum, **not** rank
```

Alternatively you can do the initialization in a join:

```
SELECT
  @rownum := @rownum +1 as ranknum
  , cust_name
  , COUNT(distinct callref) as rank 
FROM opencall 
INNER JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS initializaton
WHERE logdate LIKE '%/08/2011%' 
  AND companyname = "McDonald's Nederland" 
GROUP BY cust_name 
ORDER BY ranknum DESC
```

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
SELECT
  @rownum := @rownum +1 as ranknum
  , cust_name
  , COUNT(distinct callref) as rank 
FROM opencall  
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS initializaton
WHERE logdate BETWEEN '2011-08-01' AND '2011-08-31' 
  AND companyname LIKE "McDonald's Nederland"  <<-- like is case-insensitive
GROUP BY cust_name                             <<-- `=` can be case sensitive
ORDER BY ranknum DESC
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your help.I have tried both of these and am getting the same as the error mentioned only it states near ; in example a or '@rownum:= 0) AS initializaton
WHERE logdate like '%/08/' in your second answer

Comment: Can't do this with logdate as the logdate although holds a date time is actually a varchar field

Comment: @Annette, the first query cannot be issued in one statement, you need to execute those as two separate statements. e.g.: query.sql.text:= 'set @rownum=0;'; query.execSQL; query.sql.text:= 'select ...'; query.open;

Comment: It's a bad idea to put a date in a varchar, that's what `date` and `datetime` are for :-)

Comment: Yes I completely agree, however this is not my database but a clients and unfortunately there is nothing I can do about this. I have made my thoughts known on this however I'm stuck with it and have to work with what I have :(

Comment: You can add an extra field to the table with the logdate in a proper datetime perhaps, at least you can use an index on that field. Just add a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` that will fill the logdate2 field with the proper data.

Comment: do you mean I can't put this in a command, I'm not sure what you mean here when you say this can't be issued in one statement. The statement works in my query programme sorry if not getting what you are saying Thanks, Annette

Comment: @Annete, please don't write `programme` it makes me dizzy. You need to issue these commands as two separate queries. One after another; obviously your backend does not support multiple queries per statement.  First run the `SET ...` <enter> <run> or whatever (result: 0 rows affected), then run 'SELECT ....'

Comment: BTW the second query should run, I've tested it on my box and it works there make sure you add spaces where appropriate.

Comment: But for a command in Crystal Reports you can't do this. The command is like creating a temp table in the report. Maybe I should just create a temp table in mysql and add this table to crystal as the statement works fine in mysql server editor (Navicat)

Comment: I've copied your 2nd query again and tried this in Navicat where my statement works and this gets this error:-
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @rownum := 0) AS initializaton
WHERE logdate LIKE '%/08     and tried this in Crystal and again get the error

Comment: @Annette, I just recreated your table with testdata and copy-pasted query #2 and ran it, it says `2 rows returned in 0.00026s` so it is obviously correct. Anyway, try and replace CROSS JOIN with INNER JOIN and see if that helps, perhaps you have a very old version of MySQL.

Comment: Yes it is a very old version. I have just tried the query as follows:-Select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘ranknum’, cust_name,  count(distinct callref) as rank from opencall where logdate like '%/08/2011%' 
and companyname="McDonald's Nederland" group by cust_name order by rank desc and this goes through without error but doesn't give anything in the ranknum column. I will try inner join and let you know. Thanks so much for your help